# multiple key (composite index) search in dict

Tags: python

I have a database table with a composite index like this:

```
create table Table1
(
key1 int,
key2 int,
value1 int,
value2 char(10),
primary key(key1 , key2)
)
```

I have to create a dict from this table (using pyodbc, but the selection is not an issue).
My question is: How to define a multikey dict and after search for data in it.

I would like to achieve this SQL syntax in dictionary search:

```
select * from Table1 where key1  = 10 and key2 = 20
```

A pseudo code for the search would be:

```
myvalue = ['A', 'B']
if myvalue in mydict[key1, key2]:
    print ('OK')
```

But this is obviously wrong.
Any idea?

Comment: Could you use a tuple as your key?  `my_dict[(10, 20)]`

Comment: Yes. This is the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dict must have an immutable type as key. The simplest such structure is a `tuple`of your two database key fields. Thus you can use:

```
mydict[(key1, key2)]
```

and it should work.

Comment: `namedtuple` can also be used as key: https://alysivji.github.io/quick-hit-immutable-dict-keys.html